# How I can sort such data in R

Tags: r

Here is a sample of my data:

```
 dat<-read.table (text=" Id RA EA  R  B  M  value
    1 2 2 3 4 5 14
    2 2 3 1 2 3 9
    3 1 2 2 2 2 8
    ", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table:

```
Id  RA  EA  R   B   M
1   2   2   3   4   5
1   2   14  NA  NA  NA
2   2   3   1   2   3
2   2   9   NA  NA  NA
3   1   2   2   2   2
3   1   8   NA  NA  NA
```

I want to get blank instead of NA.
Here is my effort, but I don't get the NAs, i.e., get the blank:

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  gather(Type, EA, M, value) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Id, -RA, -EA), funs(ifelse(Type %in% "value", NA, .))) %>%
  select(Id, RA, EA, R, B, M) %>%
  arrange(Id)
```

Comment: To go with "blanks" instead of `NA` will change your numeric data to strings, irrevocably. Is that really what you want? FYI, `gather`  has been "superseded" by `pivot_longer` for a while now; any tutorial/howto that is suggesting `gather` is likely to be out of date. Not a cause for alarm atm, but certainly something you may want to consider and shift to at some point.

Comment: It's ok to get strings, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to `gather` (or pivot), we can start with:

```r
library(dplyr)
out <- bind_rows(
    select(dat, -value),
    select(dat, Id, RA, EA = value)
  ) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  arrange(Id, RA)
out
#   Id RA EA  R  B  M
# 1  1  2  2  3  4  5
# 2  1  2 14 NA NA NA
# 3  2  2  3  1  2  3
# 4  2  2  9 NA NA NA
# 5  3  1  2  2  2  2
# 6  3  1  8 NA NA NA
```

You say you want the `NA` values to be instead strings ... realize that you will not be able to do "math"-like things with those columns again. I'll infer that you want to do this for `EA` through `M`, so

```r
out %>%
  mutate(across(EA:M, ~ if_else(is.na(.), "", as.character(.))))
#   Id RA EA R B M
# 1  1  2  2 3 4 5
# 2  1  2 14      
# 3  2  2  3 1 2 3
# 4  2  2  9      
# 5  3  1  2 2 2 2
# 6  3  1  8
```

or similarly (if you're comfortable with `coalesce`ing data:

```r
out %>%
  mutate(across(EA:M, ~ coalesce(as.character(.), "")))
```